# html div grid not aligning contents in columns (vertically)

Tags: html, css

I am having div which is in rows and col. I am trying to resolve that, my header headings are not aligning with its contents which is in next rows and col. For example:

[image]

As you can see my headers are not aligned with the lower contents. Kindly check the code below and let me know the best solution for this.

```css
.orders {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.header-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #868686;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orders .order-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.orders .col.start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.orders .col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-text .header-status:before {
    content: '- Collapse';
    display: inline;
}

.header-text.active .header-status:before {
    content: '+ Expand';
}
```

```html
<div class="orders">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="col start">Name</div>
    <div class="col center">Date/Time</div>
    <div class="col center">Phone</div>
    <div class="col center">PAX</div>
    <div class="col center">Description</div>
    <div class="col center">Table</div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">New <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">description</span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">Confirm <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-06-17 12:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide">test<span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="order-row">
        <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
        <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
        <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
        <div class="col center">1</div>
        <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">test</span></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
        <div class="col start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is tabular data you should use a `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

### display: table

If your HTML is somewhat negotiable, you can solve this by enforcing a table display:

```css
.orders {
  display: table;
}

.header-row,.order-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Your HTML currently has mistakes as well, there are more columns than headlines. Two lines have even 2 columns too many.

See below snippet for a demonstration with borders and cells visualized.
This assumes your HTML is the equivalent of `table` > `tr` > `td`.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.orders {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.header-row,.order-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 3px;
}

.header-text {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #868686;
  color: white;
}

.header-text .header-status:before {
  content: '- Collapse';
  display: inline;
}

.header-text.active .header-status:before {
  content: '+ Expand';
}
```

```html
<div class="orders">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="col start">Name</div>
    <div class="col center">Date/Time</div>
    <div class="col center">Phone</div>
    <div class="col center">PAX</div>
    <div class="col center">Description</div>
    <div class="col center">Table</div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row">
    <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">New <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">description</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row">
    <div class="col start"><span class="header-text">Confirm <span class="header-status"></span></span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-06-17 12:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide">test<span style="margin-left: 9px;"></span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-row">
    <div class="col start">Mitchell Admin</div>
    <div class="col start wide">2022-05-30 10:00:00</div>
    <div class="col start wide">+1 555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="col center">1</div>
    <div class="col start wide"><span style="margin-left: 9px;">test</span></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
    <div class="col start"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I removed `div.content`, `div.header` and `div.pointer` for this to work.